# Mongoose : Sorting array in a different order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I don't know if it's possible but I would like to get the N last element of a query and get it in the response array like this [n, n-1, n-2,..., 0]

Off course with my query I got [0,1,2,...,n]

My query is Model.find({}).sort({date:-1}).limit(n).exec()

I know that I can write a js function to reverse the array but if there is already something with mongoose there is no point to doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply, `$sort` in reverse order after `$limit`

```
Model.find({}).sort({date:-1}).limit(n).sort({date:1}).exec()
                                                   ^
```

or using aggregation, `$sort` and `$limit` the results, and `$sort` again in reverse order

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$sort : {date : -1}},
    {$limit : n},
    {$sort : {date : 1}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the delay I didn't know the aggregate method so it took me some times to be sure if it could solve correctly the problem. So first method is not working, it's like the chaining is not acting. Aggregate answer the question but problem is the populate, can find a solution with the lookup but not really as powerful than populate. Are you sure about the first method ? (my mongo server version is 3.4)

Comment: the first one works fine in mongo CLI, we need to see what Model.find returns, if it returns an array or iterator, we need to sort in reverse in client side

Comment: use aggregate so that all the computation will be done in server side, rather in client side

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I need to improve my knowledge about this.